# Maven - use a remote repository also as a local repository

Tags: java, maven, svn, deployment

I've searched a whole day for a solution, but so far nothing works.

**Problem:**
I have two projects Foo and Commons using Maven. Foo depends on Commons. Commons gets deployed via scp to a remote repository on a server. The same server also checks out Foo and builds it. But when the server tries to build Foo it tries to access the Commons Jar remotely (via scp) and an error is thrown:

> Could not transfer metadata groupId:commons:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml from/to my-repository (scp://server/.m2/repository): Cannot connect. Reason: SSH_MSG_DISCONNECT: 2 Too many authentication failures for user

**Edit:** Deploying Commons to the server works. Locally packaging Foo also works. I'm using Maven 3.0.5 on the server.

**What I have tried so far:**

- Declaring the local repository in `Foo`'s `pom.xml`
- Declaring `org.apache.maven.wagon:wagon-file:2.6` as a extension in `Foo`'s `pom.xml`
- Changing Commons' version from `0.0.1-SNAPSHOT` to `0.0.1-RELEASE`

**Background:**
Project Commons is used by other projects and several people work on these projects. These people shouldn't have to check out the Project Commons, but should always have access to the most up to date Commons Jar.

**settings.xml in ~/.m2/ :**

```
  ...
  <servers>
    <server>
      <id>my-repository</id>
      <username>user</username>
      <password>password</password>
    </server>
  </servers>
  ...
```

**Common's pom.xml:**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>groupId</groupId>
  <artifactId>commons</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>commons</name>

  <distributionManagement>
    <repository>
      <id>my-repository</id>
      <url>scp://server/.m2/repository</url>
    </repository>
  </distributionManagement>

  <build>
    ...
    <extensions>
      <extension>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.wagon</groupId>
         <artifactId>wagon-ssh</artifactId>
         <version>2.6</version>
      </extension>
    </extensions>
  </build>

  <dependencies>
    ...
  </dependencies>

</project>
```

**Foo's pom.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>groupId</groupId>
    <artifactId>foo</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>1.0</version>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
            <id>my-repository</id>
            <url>scp://server/.m2/repository</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    ...

</project>
```

Comment: can you add you pom.xml for your projects please?

Comment: ... and your `settings.xml`...? Do you have a proper `<servers/>` section in your `settings.xml`?

Comment: @carlspring Yes, I have specified a server in settings.xml. Deploying the Commons Jar to the server works, but packaging the Foo Jar on the server doesn't work. The problem is that the server tries to connect to itself remotely to access the Commons Jar.

Comment: I have found a solution but cannot answer my own question. In the server's settings.xml I added a mirror for the server repository, which points to the local repository. see http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-mirror-settings.html

Comment: @DominikSeitz What URL did you use exactly to make this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make it work, I had to add a mirror for the server-repository in the server's `.m2/settings.xml`. `<mirrorOf>` has to be the same as the repository's `<id>` defined in `pom.xml`.

**server:~/.m2/settings.xml:**

```
  ...
  <mirrors>
    ...
    <mirror>
      <id>local-mirror</id>
      <mirrorOf>my-repository</mirrorOf>
      <url>file://${user.home}/.m2/repository</url>
    </mirror>
  </mirrors>
  ...
```

Source: http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-mirror-settings.html

Comment: I found that if I want EVERYTHING to be resolved here and not go to maven central to look, I needed to use `<mirrorOf>external:*</mirrorOf>`